# rails app current_user method does not work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Hi I'm fairly new to coding and I'm building a rails/react habit builder app. Everything works fine when running on local server. However I've switched the database over to postgres and deployed to heroku, and nearly everything works except for a create action in one of my of controllers.

```
            def create 
                current_user.identities.build(identity_params)
                if identity.save
                    render json: IdentitySerializer.new(identity).serialized_json
                else
                    render json: { error: identity.errors.messages }, status: 422
                end
            end
```

here is my current_method

```
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
```

here is the error in my heroku log

```
2020-11-16T16:14:03.944788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/categories" host=atomic-habits-app.herokuapp.com request_id=94543abb-1522-464f-9c8e-44e7bc6f765b fwd="68.199.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=103ms status=304 bytes=445 protocol=https
2020-11-16T16:14:16.585828+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-16T16:14:16.585700 #8]  INFO -- : [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b] Started POST "/api/v1/identities" for 68.199.184.23 at 2020-11-16 16:14:16 +0000
2020-11-16T16:14:16.587457+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-16T16:14:16.587389 #8]  INFO -- : [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b] Processing by Api::V1::IdentitiesController#create as HTML
2020-11-16T16:14:16.587570+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-16T16:14:16.587508 #8]  INFO -- : [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b]   Parameters: {"identity"=>{"category_id"=>"1", "name"=>"test", "description"=>"test", "standard"=>"7"}}
2020-11-16T16:14:16.590058+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-11-16T16:14:16.589975 #8]  INFO -- : [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Allocations: 570)
2020-11-16T16:14:16.591415+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-11-16T16:14:16.591334 #8] FATAL -- : [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b]
2020-11-16T16:14:16.591416+00:00 app[web.1]: [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b] NoMethodError (undefined method `identities' for nil:NilClass):
2020-11-16T16:14:16.591417+00:00 app[web.1]: [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b]
2020-11-16T16:14:16.591417+00:00 app[web.1]: [f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b] app/controllers/api/v1/identities_controller.rb:17:in `create'
2020-11-16T16:14:16.592938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/v1/identities" host=atomic-habits-app.herokuapp.com request_id=f2c1ff5a-c6b8-4304-89a4-7174caed6c0b fwd="68.199.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=1841 protocol=https
```

And again, this create action works perfectly fine when I run it on my local server. And in production the create method works for signing up a user and creating a session. And when creating a session I console.log the response from the sessions controller which includes

```
render json: {
          logged_in: true,
          current: current_user, 
          user: @user
        }
```

And the current user object gets logged to the console upon login.
So im not sure if the issue is relationship related between identity and users (user has many identities), or if there is an issue relying on sessions in production? I've really made no progress debugging this. Any ideas or advice is very much appreciated. Sorry if I left out any necessary code. Here are links to repo and heroku
https://atomic-habits-app.herokuapp.com/
https://github.com/mattkuras/Habit-Helper

edit**

Thank you Eyeslandic for this response it seems to be working.

"Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_habit-helper', domain: 'localhost:3000' could be the problem, referencing port 3000 especially"

I changed port 3000 to :all in my config/initializers/session_store.rb. The cookie wasnt properly being set

Comment: `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_habit-helper', domain: 'localhost:3000'` could be the problem, referencing port 3000 especially

Comment: this solved it!